# Параметр с переменной арностью

Tags: java, параметры

> **Параметр с переменной арностью** с типом элемента, недоступным во время выполнения, может привести к замусориванию кучи и породить предупреждения о непроверяемом преобразовании во время компиляции.

Что означает параметр с переменной арностью?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я думаю речь идет о `varargs`:

```
void method(String ... strings){
    for(String str: strings)
       System.out.println(str);
}

method("hello");
method("hello","world");
```

А данное предупреждение выводится, когда у параметра подразумевается параметризированный `generic`'ами тип.

```
<T> void method(Iterator<T> iterators){
    ,,,
}
```

Чтобы понять, почему это происходит, нужно разобраться, как работают `varargs`. Приведенный выше метод, преобразуется в такой:

```
<T> void method(Iterator<T>[]array){
    ...
}
```

А при вызове, параметры записываются в созданный массив:

```
method(new Iterator[]{param1,param2});
```

Заметьте, что при создании массива нельзя указать `generic`, т.е. фактически создается массив объектов типа `Iterator` с параметризированный типом `Object`. Из за этого могут возникнуть проблемы, о чем компилятор вежливо и сообщает.

Убрать предупреждение можно пометив метод аннотацией `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, либо начиная с *java 7* `@SafeVarargs`